# Android Built-in Data Usage API

Tags: android

One of the highlights of Android 4.0 is built-in [data usage tracking](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html). Is there anything in the Android APIs that can access the information?

With the `TrafficStats` class, you can build your own traffic monitoring tools, but you can't grab the limits/warnings and existing data usage data that is present. So any apps using `TrafficStats` automatically start of with 0 data, where as if possible, I would like to be able to grab the user limits/warnings and existing data usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything in the Android APIs that can access the information?

Alas, no.

Comment: It's really unfortunate. I would love to build a widget that can display the information instead of requiring the user to go through multiple-screens just to check their existing data usage.